# Sinatra creating a delete http request using name="_method". What is going on?

Tags: sinatra

I read this:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark

and I still have the question of how this html form is working behind the scenes.

```
<form action='/<%= idea.id %>' method='POST'>
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
      <input type='submit' value="delete"/>
</form>
```

Is Sinatra looking specifically at the `<input>` name field and does that _method mean something internally to Sinatra and Rails? If so, what is going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - as documented in the Sinatra [Readme](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Available%20Settings) :

```
Use _method magic to allow put/delete forms in browsers that don't support it.
```

The "magic" is actually implemented in the Rack middleware, see the code in ['lib/rack/methodoverride.rb'](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/ab172af1b63f0d8e91ce579dd2907c43b96cf82a/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb)